# open dialog on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Want to open a dialog on onclick() event on button

file.html

```
<div class="new"></div>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".new").append('<div class="butn"><input type= "button"class ="btn btn-info " onclick="dialogopen()" value= "Reply"><>');
    });
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
        }
    });

    function dialogopen() {
        alert("hello new");
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");

    }
</script>
```

What wrong i am doing i dont know. Please help me out for this.

Comment: you have to bind the event first.

Comment: Additional `)` while closing `dialogopen` function

Comment: A simple trip to JSFiddle would have 1) given your fellow SO users a better way to help troubleshoot your issue AND 2) notified you that you had an error in your syntax keeping the script from working properly.

Answer (score 2):

you have an extra  ) at the end

```
    function dialogopen() {
      alert("hello new");
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have additional `)` while closing `dialogopen` function, You need to remove it

```
function dialogopen() {
  alert("hello new");
  $("#dialog").dialog("open");
//});
}; //Removed ) in this line
```

Also you should use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach for dynamic elements instead of inline event handlers.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Example

```
$(document).on('click', ".btn-info", function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/n9toucbf/)

Comment: its not working because i am adding button through the jquery.

Comment: @Gaurav, Thats why I have given solution of event delegation, that will work, I have added demo

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$(".new")
  .append('<div class="butn"><input type= "button"class ="btn btn-info " value= "Reply"><>')
  .bind('click', function() {
      dialogopen();
})
```

and

```
function dialogopen() {
    alert("hello new");
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );

};
```